# how to convert List<Doctor> items = new List(); to List<String>? can you help me?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to convert List items = new List(); to List? can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Doctor> items = new List();
```

--- add data to `items` list ---

then,

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>(items.size());
for (Doctor doctor: items) {
    strings.add(Objects.toString(doctor, null));
}
```

if you are using java 8,

```
List<String> strings = items.stream()
   .map(doctor -> Objects.toString(doctor , null))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: i am using flutter dart, i forgot to include

Answer (score 0):

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/List-class.html

^ Use `.map` method of `List<Doctor>` instance.

For example

```
var itemStrings = items.map((doc) {
    // Title property as example
    return doc.title;
}).toList();
```

I recommend that you take [dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)